# TextView lines keep changing when i swipe target view with MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'm using `MotionLayout` to swipe a view from right to left.
To swipe, I made a motionScene.xml and used two transitions. one is for the button the other is for the container. The behavior of the two transitions is same. The problem is that the `TextView`'s lines in the container keep changing while the view is being laid out. please check below. 
[image] 
As you can see, the `TextView`'s lines keep changing from multi-lines to 3 lines.
What i want to is to show like the final state(now, it would be 3 lines). But it doesn't mean i can set `android:maxLines="3"`(or with`android:ellipsize="end"`).
I want to show this like `DrawerLayout`. When i swipe a view, `DrawerLayout` shows the content that has already been created.

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_left_12dp_gray333"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="T\ne\ns\nt"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/container"
        layout="@layout/view_item_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

### activity_main_scene.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:duration="500">
        <OnSwipe
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/container"
            app:dragDirection="dragLeft"
            app:touchAnchorSide="left" />
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:duration="500">
        <OnSwipe
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/button"
            app:dragDirection="dragLeft"
            app:touchAnchorSide="left" />
    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

I also thought about how to fix the size, hide it off the screen using translationX properties, and bring it back to the screen when it was end transition, but it didn't work out. 
How can i make it? is it possible with MotionLayout?

Comment: That's a good idea. I should've thought to suggest `MotionLayout` as a possibility. I've got something that's relatively simple here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EYpqy0AzP-4zxlKoTaWFQklLHDn6-44h/view?usp=share_link. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o3Dw.gif. However, it can be swiped open anywhere along that whole edge, which I seem to recall is the general behavior for `MotionLayout`. Can you also swipe your example anywhere?

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for answering my question again Mike! And Yes, it's totally good because I'll use the `MotionLayout` in a `ViewGroup` which is a part of `Activity`.
I have one more question, When I compared the code between you and me, the important difference might be the `LinearLayout` in the `view_item_container.xml`. Why did you think of `LinearLayout`?

Comment: I always prefer simpler components, and `LinearLayout` is made specifically for plain stacks or rows, so it's both a little better suited to something like this, and a bit easier to set up for it. In any case, it's not the different `ViewGroup`; it's the `ConstraintSet`s. In my start set, the drawer has `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"`, which is pushing it out of the parent's right side. The end set has `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`, which is drawer open, with its right edge aligned with the parent's. Your setup is varying the drawer's width, which is why it squishes

Comment: Thank you so much Mike. You inspired me! You saved my day. If you lived in Korea, I would have served meal for you. Thank you so much!

Comment: After looking at this again, I initially misunderstood how `<OnSwipe>` works. It would make more sense for our `touchAnchorId` to be the drawer, really, and we are able to restrict the touch area that initiates the swipe with `touchRegionId`, which is what our `button` should be. I've updated the `<MotionScene>` in the example I linked above, and I think it now works exactly like you were wanting: you can drag the drawer only with the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

The starting constraint set need to be the ending size.
The simple answer to this is to use `Start_toEndOf="Parent"`
Then you need to figure out how to keep the width of the view constant
In your cast we know the with is the width of the parent.
This is one way to do it.

```
   <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </ConstraintSet>
    
``
```